# jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes is not working for cxf-xjc-plugin?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf-xjc-plugin

cxf-xjc-plugin isn't working as expected.

I am getting the following issue after a clean install in maven (java11)

> vendor extension bindings (jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes) are not
> allowed in the strict mode. Use -extension

What is the error cause ?

here the plugin conifugration :

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <xsdOptions>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>src/main/resources/xsd/Content.xsd</xsd>
                                        <bindingFile>src/main/xjb/rules.xml</bindingFile>
                                    <catalog>src/main/resources/xsd/catalog.cat</catalog>
                                </xsdOption>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>src/main/resources/xsd/e-BoxDefinitionType.xsd</xsd>
                                    <bindingFile>src/main/xjb/rules.xml</bindingFile>
                                    <catalog>src/main/resources/xsd/catalog.cat</catalog>
                                </xsdOption>
                            </xsdOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Here my rules :